# Why are interaction effects for categorical variables under our treatment not included?

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data, continuous-data

We're trying to see the effects of treatments on the download speed of mobile data in 4 locations, with three variables: SIMs, Locations, and Time. SIMs has 2 factor levels, Locations has 4 factor levels, and Time has 2 factor levels.

[image]

SIMs' factor levels are the network providers' SIM cards we used: Globe and Smart. For some reason, R isn't including Globe, timeAM, and locationsArea2 for the linear model. (AM is one of two factor levels for Time, and Area2 is one of four factor levels for Locs)

[image]

A colleague said that Globe:Area2:AM is our intercept. I'm not versed enough in R to know what that means.

Not sure what we're doing wrong here, or if we're doing anything wrong at all.

Comment: It's difficult to answer without data to examine and reproduce the problem, but I assume this is because the levels missing are the model's reference levels.

Comment: Sounds like your understanding of regression methods needs buttressing. CV.com is a better fit for this question. It’s not specific to R.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed unrelated to R.

When you have a categorical variable, then it gets *dummy coded*, i.e., it gets split up into multiple regressor columns in the design matrix, with a 1 encoding presence and 0 absence of the relevant factor level. However, you also have the intercept column. Therefore, you encode a categorical predictor with $k$ levels into $k-1$ 0-1 predictor columns, where one factor level does not get a column. An observation with that "reference level" gets zeros in all $k-1$ predictors, and its fit is the intercept. Usually, the "reference level" is the one that comes first alphabetically, simply as a convention - and that is precisely what is happening here.

You can find a lot of information by googling for "regression categorical variable reference level" or similar, e.g., [this](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/spss/faq/coding-systems-for-categorical-variables-in-regression-analysis/). I personally would recommend working my way through a simple example with a single three-level categorical predictor, setting up the design matrix and checking which factor level gets omitted (use `model.matrix()` in R), calculating the model fits for the various levels by hand. Once you have a firm grasp on that, try a more complex model with interactions between two different categorical variables.